# Magento 2 TypeError Undefined products images not displaying / js not loading

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-images, jquery, requirejs

At home page, product category view and product detailed view page images are not loading / displaying at firefox and less frequently at chrome.

I am using **magento 2.2.6** upgraded from **2.2.2** and **porto theme** upgrade to 3.1.5.

Inspect shows after clean cache:

1.- TypeError: src is undefined

2.- TypeError: $.ui is undefined

3.- TypeError: $.widget is not a function

4.- TypeError: $.widget is not a function (twice)

5.- TypeError: $.ui is undefined

Inspect shows after reload home page a few less:

1.- TypeError: src is undefined

2.- TypeError: $.ui is undefined

3.- TypeError: $.ui is undefined

exception.log shows from 2 days ago (not today):

> [2018-09-26 16:02:26] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats!
>   Warning!stat(): stat failed for
>   /home/xxx/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/es_AR/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot
>   gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for
>   /home/xxx/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/es_AR/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
>   at
>   /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"}
>   []

any help will be great !

my site: https://www.calzadosyoyito.cl

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After many cigarretes and heart attacks, I found what was trouble all my javascript stuff, It was a scripts that seems to call their own js as reported by another guy whom I lost their link :(, but I remembered. My script was provided by McAfee :

script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js" async>  /script

So I deleted and voila !!! :)

Cheers !